# How to Create Web based Mirror Tool using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an ecommerce website for Glasses. Where I want to put a feature to try the glasses on your face or on some sample faces. The perfect example for this is one this site

http://www.glasses2you.co.uk/prescription-glasses/gender/mens-glasses

See the **Try in Mirror** option on this website.

I can see it has been built using Flash Actionscript.
Any suggestion how can I build this using Javascript through jQuery or such related tools?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically, you need to position the glasses over the portrait image.

Comment: In what way are you asking? Of course you can do it in javascript, but what question are you trying to ask?

Comment: I am just asking for suggestions on how to built it. E.g. some suggested tools, or some steps to follow

Answer (score 1):

Simply position the image of the glasses on top of the photo.

You can do this with CSS, which can be set with JavaScript.  Use the [CSS `position` property](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).

For your source images of glasses, use PNG so that you can have a proper alpha channel.  You will probably want to specify offsets for each image individually.